# Git merge gone wrong, strange history

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I work on this github repo: https://github.com/Sable/mclab

The history on the develop branch is a bit wonky. This is what happened:

- Person A with a screwed up environment pushed some commits that were dated 1970.
- Person B tried to merge his "fragile" branch into develop and push to github. But this happened: https://github.com/Sable/mclab/compare/aa6e2c9d74...9209f45db4; it seems like every commit on the repo ever was pushed.

Now the history is strange, e.g. https://github.com/Sable/mclab/commits/develop?page=58; you can see the first commits from 2008, followed by the screwed-up-environment 1970 commits, followed (on the next page) by more recent commits which should be at the tip of the history.

So I have two questions:

1. What exactly happened? I am guessing the merge was screwed up somehow by the 1970 commits but I am not sure.
2. What would  be the best way to "fix" things? I know you can't really undo a push; I'd basically like the history on develop to look the way it did before this happened. I'm okay with doing weird surgery on the repo to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I have figured out.

The merge went fine -- merging doesn't depend on timestamps (e.g. a `git log --date-order` shows a sensible order). But the history looks strange because timestamps determine (among other things) the default order commits are presented in in `git log`, and apparently the commit compare view in GitHub.

This is what I did:

- Started with my `develop` branch from before the merge happened (which does have the 1970 commits).
- Created a new branch based on `develop`.
- Ran `git reset --hard` on develop, returning to the parent of the first 1970 commit
- Rebased the new branch interactively onto develop, selecting "edit" for all the commits whose dates I wanted to change and picking sensible dates for them
- Deleted develop branch on github
- Pushed new develop branch to github

This seems to have worked fine, although I had to instruct people to be careful before pulling (either clone a fresh repo, or reset back to the same commit I did before rebasing).